Why it's valid to write `typeof someArray[number]` in TypeScript?
Given an interface, we can access its properties of a specific key type, e.g. string:
interface AB {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
}

type PropertiesByString = AB[keyof AB & string]

This works because keyof AB & string is "a" | "b", which are all valid keys of AB. The same logic doesn't apply to arrays:
const MyArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];
 
type Person = typeof MyArray[number];

The code is valid, but the number here includes 4 and much more. Why number is allowed here?

The type of MyArray is Array<...> and Array has a number index signature in its type definition.  The inferred type of AB has no index signature, number or otherwise, so it doesn't work.  TypeScript cares about the types more than the actual values. It's always considered acceptable to index into an array with an arbitrary number, regardless of what data might be actually present in it.  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

When you write
const myArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];
 

TypeScript infers it to be of type
// const myArray: { name: string; age: number; }[]

which is just a shorthand way of writing
// const myArray: Array<{ name: string; age: number; }>

so myArray has an array type. If you look at the TypeScript type definition for Array<T>, it has a numeric index signature:
interface Array<T> {
    // ⋮ 
    [n: number]: T;
}

That means TypeScript will allow you to index into it with a numeric key. In particular, the indexed access Array<T>[number] will just give you T back.

You seem to be asking why it doesn't complain because the contents of the array don't have values at every numeric index. The answer is because the type doesn't keep track of the contents.
Furthermore, index signatures of the form {[key: K]: V} don't mean "every key of type K exists in this object and has a value of type V".  Instead it means "if a key of type K exists in this object, then its value is of type V." So (typeof myArray)[number] is always { name: string; age: number; }, even though you can expect to see undefined in practice if you do an arbitrary indexing operation.  You can turn on --noUncheckedIndexedAccess if you want to see undefined as a possible value for an indexing operation:
const person = myArray[4];
// if --noUncheckedIndexedAccess is off
// const person: { name: string; age: number; } 

// if --noUncheckedIndexedAccess is on
// const person: { name: string; age: number; } | undefined 

but the indexed access type will remain the same.

There are tuple types which constrain arrays to containing particular value types at particular indices and whose length is known in advance. If you use a const assertion on your initializing array literal you'd get something closer to the type you're presumably looking for:
const myArrayConst = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
] as const;

/* const myArrayConst: readonly [{
    readonly name: "Alice";
    readonly age: 15;
}, {
    readonly name: "Bob";
    readonly age: 23;
}, {
    readonly name: "Eve";
    readonly age: 38;
}] */

Now TypeScript knows that the length is 3 and will complain if it sees you index with a literal number known to be out of bounds:
let personConst: Person;
personConst = myArrayConst[0]; // okay

personConst = myArrayConst[4]; // error! no element at index '4'
// error! Type 'undefined' is not assignable

But again, this doesn't change what happens at the numeric index signature:
type PersonConst = (typeof myArrayConst)[number];
/* type PersonConst = {
    readonly name: "Alice";
    readonly age: 15;
} | {
    readonly name: "Bob";
    readonly age: 23;
} | {
    readonly name: "Eve";
    readonly age: 38;
} */

myArrayConst[Math.random()] // okay, number is still a valid index

The indexing is still allowed, and the indexed access still gives you the element type without undefined.
Playground link to code

Using number is a special way of indexing array types.
A TypeScript array type (in comparison to a tuple) does not have a fixed length. typeof MyArray is just { name: string; age: number; }[]. The runtime variable array may contain 3 items but on type level there is no information about that. Theoretically the array could have any length. Therefore, it is often more concise to index with number than to use random indexes that all index the same type.
typeof MyArray[4], and typeof MyArray[3] and also typeof MyArray[23802302] are all valid. Try it!

I upvote for your kindness and that I didn't know that typeof MyArray[23802302] isn't an error. But the line "number is a special way" and the link can't resolve my confusion of "why it's valid".
